# Webpage shows white right margin on mobile screen. How to remove this white margin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have created a webpage using Bootstrap and CSS3. Then I used the grid system to make it responsive on all screens. But I am facing a problem, when I open it on mobile, it shows white margin on right and makes little bit horizontal scroll. I tried everything but nothing worked for me. How do I solve this problem?

See my webpage: https://manpreet9112.github.io/JS-website/home.html

code: https://github.com/manpreet9112/JS-website

Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it's a very frequent problem with bs3. Until you understand the principle of bootstrap grid system. You should never change `.container`'s side paddings because inside `.row`s have negative side margins.

All you need to fix your webpage is to remove this (`design.css` line 185):

```
.container{padding:10px 0;}
```

If default bootstrap grid's margins and paddings doesn't fit your needs, you can overwrite it, but firstly you should learn how it works taking into account that you should make changes for all resolutions.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. But you may see, only PRODUCT LIST div does not have default bottom padding. why?

Comment: Is my slider gallary looking good in mobile view or it need changes? because I saw it's height does not looking good in mobile view.

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman, because you didn't set bottom padding for product list `col-`s as you did for `#about`. And I'm afraid that Stack Overflow isn't a place to discuss if anything looks good or not (take a look at the rules of community). But yes, carousel needs changes as well as a lot of other things on the page.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Voloshin. Sorry if I break the rules. I will my rest of problems.  Thanks a lot again.